# Flutter Firestore update if exist if not create

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know if specific document exists, update that document and if not create that document is possible in Firestore or not.
For example, user entered some tag with post, then look like this
 `Firestore.instance.collection('tags').document(tag here).updateData()`.
Is there any way if that document doesn't exist, then create method or do I have to check if exists before writing it?

Comment: Just commenting that this was also relevant for me for the web sdk, and that Doug's answer below worked for that as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know how it works with Flutter specifically (I haven't written a line of Dart in my life), but the other client APIs allow a second argument to set() (or in your case setData()) that allows a document to be either created if not existing, or merged in the case that it already does.

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) for examples in other languages.  It might just be a matter of passing `{ merge: true }` as the second argument, like the web example, or possibly use of `SetOptions.merge()` like Java.

Answer (score 31):

**Update**

on newer Firebase SDK the syntax changed; Firebase is FirebaseFirestore and setData is deprecated in favor of set + SetOptions.

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.
  collection('tags').
  document(tag).
  set(data, SetOptions(merge: true))
```

---

@Doug is right, there is an option in the Flutter Firestore API:

```
Firestore.instance.
  collection('tags').
  document(tag here).
  setData(data, merge: true)
```

From the doc:

> `setData(Map<String, dynamic> data, {bool merge: false}) → Future<void>`
>
> Writes to the document referred to by this DocumentReference. If the document does not yet exist, it will be created.
>
> If **merge** is true, the provided data will be merged into an existing document instead of overwriting.

Compare that with the doc from `updateData`, which explicitly fails.

> `updateData(Map<String, dynamic> data) → Future<void>`
>
> Updates fields in the document referred to by this DocumentReference.
>
> **If no document exists yet, the update will fail**.

Comment: `If no document exists yet, the update will fail` does this result in any error which might cause the app to crash?

Comment: Is this possible that I can update a field value of all the documents which are matched with given where single/multiple conditions? eg. `FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('messages')
        .where('encSenderUId', isEqualTo: widget.encUId)
        .where('encReceiverUId', isEqualTo: _loggedInUserId)
        ...update Map code....` Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: I am facing the same problem can you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/q/69287110/13984728

Answer (score 8):

#### Update 2021:

Use `set` on the document and provide a `SetOptions` with `merge: true`. From the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/set.html):

> Sets data on the document, overwriting any existing data. If the document does not yet exist, it will be created.
>
> If SetOptions are provided, the data will be merged into an existing document instead of overwriting.

```dart
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
collection
    .doc('doc_id')
    .set(yourData, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

Answer (score 4):

It appears that as of 2020-03-31, yes, you have to check whether or not the document exists first. `setData(data, merge: true)` doesn't actually obey the `merge` parameter. [Here is the relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1212)

The behavior I'm getting is equivalent to a regular `setData()`, so it silently overwrites any existing data. An expensive workaround:

```
final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
final collection = 'my_collection';
final documentId = 'my_document';
final snapShot = await _db.collection(collection).document(documentId).get();
if(snapShot.exists){
  _db.collection(collection).document(documentId).updateData(myMap);
} else {
  _db.collection(collection).document(documentId).setData(myMap);
}
```

Comment: I want to do similar thing but I do not want to use documentId, my query is based on other columns..Can you help?

Comment: If I understand correctly, in the example above, you would change the query in `snapShot =` to be whatever you need it to be. Then, in the first case, where `snapShot.exists`, you would replace `.document(documentId)` with `.document(snapShot.document.documentId)`, using the snapshot's document ID even though you didn't use it in the query. The second half of the conditional can remain the same, setting the ID for the new document however you usually do.

Answer (score 1):

You want to upsert and best way to do with is:

```
Future updateUserFirestore(
  String name,
  String dob,
  String email,
  String sex
) {

    return _getUserDetailsDocumentRef().update({
      'name': name,
      'dob': dob,
      'email': email,
      'sex': sex
    }).catchError((e) => {

      _getUserDetailsDocumentRef().set({
        'name': name,
        'dob': dob,
        'email': email,
        'sex': sex
      }, SetOptions(merge: true))
    });
}
```